# How can I add my Microsoft Account calendar to Outlook 2016?

Tags: windows-10, calendar, microsoft-account, microsoft-outlook-2016

I use a custom email address, *stijn@example.com*, as my Microsoft account. I use it for both my Windows 10 device and Windows 10 Mobile device.

On the mobile device, it serves as the account for my personal calendar. I have this calendar available in the Calendar app on W10 and W10M.

Now I want to add this calendar to Outlook 2016, but I cannot figure out how to do it. Automatic lookup fails because it tries to look up account settings for *example.com*, so I tried manual settings with the following information:

- E-mail Address: stijn@example.com
- Mail server: dub408-m.hotmail.com
- User Name: stijn@example.com

I got the mail server from the Calendar app's account settings:

[image: screenshot of calendar settings]

When continuing in the *Add Account* wizard, I immediately get the following error:

> Log onto Exchange ActiveSync mail server (EAS): The username or password you entered isn’t working. Please try typing them again.

I've tried typing the login details again, but it didn't help. I'm also using 2FA for the Microsoft Account, in case that matters.

How can I add this calendar to Outlook 2016?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that 2FA [is the cause](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/app-passwords-two-step-verification):

> If you've turned on two-step verification and you see an incorrect password error with an app or device, you'll need to get and enter a unique app password to sign in. Once you've signed in with your app password, you're all set to use that app or device. You'll need to create and sign in with a new app password for each app or device that can't prompt you for a security code.

I managed to login with the settings from my question and an app password.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `s.outlook.com` as your mail server. Relevant information can be found [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/outlook/send-receive-from-app).

Comment: I get the same error.